# Maven Tomcat7 run a dependency war

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have a question regarding maven and its tomcat7 plugin :)

I have the following maven projects:

- plugin1: plain java project packaged as jar
- plugin2: plain java project packaged as jar
- webapp: standalone webapp project packaged as jar

those three project are properly build in maven and the outcome works fine:

- I can use the jars from plugin1/plugin2
- I can deploy the webapp war file to a web container
- I can run tomcat7:run to start the webapp

Now, I need to provide different packaging of the webapp containing specific plugin setup. 
i.e. I want to generate a war file with webapp + plugin1 and another one with webapp + pugin2

To achieve this, I have created 2 additionnal maven projects that declare dependancies on the webapp project + the appropriate plugin projects and are packaged as wars.
The generated war files have the expected content, and can be deployed to a tomcat, but when I try to use the maven tomcat plugin (tomcat7:run again), it simply doesnt start anything.

Though this is not blocking for me (my main point was to generate the war files), I have the feeling that I missed something.

the pom.xml for those aggregate projects looks like this (note that there is absolutly no code in those projects, these were just created for packaging with specific dependancies convenience).

```
<groupId>my.project</groupId>
<artifactId>live1</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>MyWebapp</name>

<properties>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>plugin1</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>MyWebapp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>
                <server>localhost</server>
                <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thanks !

note: long time lurker, first time asker here, if some information is missing tell me :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the structure of your project it may not be suficient to just add a dependency of type war. You may need also to configure `<overlays>` as described here [maven-war-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins-archives/maven-war-plugin-LATEST/overlays.html).
It looks like your final war does not provide the full web configuration that you expect. With `overlays` you can configure how the resources from the dependency will be packed into your final web app.

There must be some difference in the way that your external tomcat starts the app compared to the tomcat7 plugin. May be you can try -X option :

```
mvn -X tomcat7:run
```

This should log out some details, of what the embedded tomcat is configuring..

Comment: Hi, I indeed read about overlays, but it seemed to me that this could be of use if my issue was about the final war generation. In my current setup the war generated in /target is OK (and deploys properly). Still overlays might be a way to fix the tomcat7:run behavior, but then I didnt get how to do it :( [I will read the link you provided again !]

Comment: Theres a lot of debug information ! but none make sense to me :(